# Table has no columns when drawing google charts with JSON and Laravel from MySQL database

Tags: php, json, laravel, google-visualization, data-visualization

I have this situation where i execute a query and get the following table from the database:

```
GRAD_ACAD, subtotal
'DOC', 79
'LIC', 1
'MTR', 6
```

By following the example showed in the docs, i call my controller in the URL:
...

```
// Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {
      var jsonData = $.ajax({
          url: "{{URL::route('query01')}}",
          dataType:"json",
          async: false
          }).responseText;

      // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

      // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
      var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, {width: 400, height: 240});
```

...

When i open the view, i get the *Table has no columns* error. However, by using firebug i do see the json which looks like the following:

```
[{"GRAD_ACAD":"DOC","subtotal":79},{"GRAD_ACAD":"LIC","subtotal":1},{"GRAD_ACAD":"MTR","subtotal":6}]
```

I understand that i neeed to specify separately the column names and the rows. How do i do it? Or how do I fix this?

Comment: Your result has each row as an object.  You'll need to iterate through your array and reformat to match the input required by DataTable.  See the docs for data table at https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataTable

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is to format rightly your json to an array, then you can use `google.visualization.arrayToDataTable`

```
function right_format(data){
var arr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var element = [];
    if (arr.length === 0){
        var columns = Object.keys(data[i]);
        arr.push(columns);
    };
    for (var j = 0; j < columns.length; j++){
        element.push(parseFloat(data[i][columns[j]]));
    };
    arr.push(element);
};
return arr;
```

};